# Yii2 - Como ordenar o gridview em um formulário [POST] sem perder os filtros usando arrayDataProvider

Tags: classificação, gridview, yii2

Tenho um formulário com 14 campos de pesquisa sendo que metade desses campos são arrays, por esse motivo o método do formulário é POST contrário apresenta erro

> (414 - Request URI too long).

Estou usando o `gridview` para renderizar os resultados com paginação = **10**, porém quando eu clico pra mostrar os resultados da segunda aba do `gridview` Yii2 não consegue interpretar o request e todos os resultados se perdem. Eu notei que o `gridview` utiliza por default do framework o método `GET` isso ele se perde e "some" com os resultados.

O mesmo acontece quando tento utilizar a ordenação do `gridview`. Preciso ordenar e usar o `gridview` com o formulário POST.

Answer (score 0):

[RESOLVIDO]
Para encurtar a URL e conseguir utilizar o método GET eu usei o seguinte código:

```
class MyModelExemple extends ActiveRecord 
{
    private $_formName;

    // Função que vai "renomear" a model
    public function formName()
    {
        if (!empty($this->_formName)) {
            return $this->_formName;
        } else {
            return parent::formName();
        }
    }

    // Função que vai setar o "nome temporário" da model
    public function setFormName($formName)
    {
        if (!empty($formName)) {
            $this->_formName = $formName;
        }
    }
}
```

CONTROLLER:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    //Instanciando a model
    $modelExempleInstancied = new MyModelExemple();
    //Setando o nome temporário para a model = A
    $modelExempleInstancied->setFormName('A');

    /* Todo seu código */

    return $this->render($view, [
                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                'model'        => $modelExempleInstancied
    ]);       
}
```

Quando a model for passada para view a mesma será renderizada com o nome 'A', sem renomear a model o nome do campo seria "MyModelExemple[NomeCampo]" mas agora o campo tem o nome "A[NomeCampo]", dessa forma minha URL está muito menor e não tenho problemas de (414 - Request URI too long).